# Scraping from Same-named Tags with Python / BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm getting my toes wet with BeautifulSoup and am hung up on scraping some particular info. The HTML looks like the following, for example:

```
<div class="row">
  ::before
    <div class="course-short clearfix">
      ::before
        <div class="course-meta col-sm-12">
           <dl>
              <dt>Language:</dt>
              <dd>English</dd>
              <dt>Author:</dt>
              <dd>John Doe</dd>
              <dt>Institution:</dt>
              <dd>American University</dd>
           </dl>
        </div>
       ...
<div class="row">
  ::before
    <div class="course-short clearfix">
      ::before
        <div class="course-meta col-sm-12">
           <dl>
              <dt>Language:</dt>
              <dd>English</dd>
              <dt>Author:</dt>
              <dd>John Doe, Jr.</dd>
              <dt>Institution:</dt>
              <dd>Another University</dd>
           </dl>
        </div>
       ...
```

Each page has about 10 `<div class="row">` tags, each with the same `<dt>` and `<dd>` pattern (e.g., Language, Author, Institution).

I am trying to scrape the `<dd>American University</dd>` info, ultimately to create a loop so that I can get that info specific to each `<div class="row">` tag.

I've managed the following so far:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("http://www.oeconsortium.org/courses/search/?search=statistics")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html.parser")
institutions = [x.text.strip() for x in bsObj.find_all('div', 'course-meta col-sm-12', 'dd')]
```

But that only gives me the following mess for each respective `<div class="row">` :

`Language:\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tEnglish\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\nAuthor:\nJohn Doe\nInstitution:\nAmerican University\n`
`Language:\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tEnglish\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\nAuthor:\nJohn Doe, Jr.\nInstitution:\nAnother University\n
...`

(I know how to `.strip()`; that's not the issue.)

I can't figure out how to target that third `<dd></dd>` for each respective `<div class="row">`. I feel like it may be possible by also targeting the `<dt>Institution:</dt>` tag (which is "Institution" in every respective case), but I can't figure it out.

Any help is appreciated. I am trying to make a LOOP so that I can loop over, say, ten `<div class="row">` instances and just pull out the info specific to the "Institution" `<dd>` tag.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to target that third `<dd></dd>` for each respective `<div class="row">`

`find_all` will return a list of all occurrences, so you could just take the third element of the result. Although you may want to wrap the whole thing with `try catch` to prevent `IndexError`
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all

I'd make a function out of this code to reuse it for different pages:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html.parser")

result = []
for meta in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'course-meta'}):
    try:
        institution = meta.find_all('dd')[2].text.strip()
        result.append(institution)  # or whatever you like to store it
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Comment: Very cool. Thank you. I was hung up on the indexing part, but it makes total sense now, and the function works. Thanks again!